# Topicality of question on how to give feedback

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, questions

Would a question on how to give good constructive feedback to other writers fit this Exchange? Would it be too broad? That would be my main concern, but I believe that we could give a list of guidelines for how to approach giving a critique without the need for a dissertation on the subject.

If it is too broad, are there any details you would ask for that might help me, the asker, narrow down the question to something on-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about how to review or critique are on-topic.  (Editing is on-topic, and this is related.)  Your question as proposed feels too broad, but you could narrow it down by including:

- type of work (critiquing poetry differs from critiquing API documentation)
- size of the work (people probably approach novels differently from short stories)
- whether this is a one-time critique or part of an ongoing process where the reviewer might see several drafts, be part of a regular group, or similar